# Inequality about $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i)^2 $ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality

When I do some thing about infinite matrix, I want a inequality which is the infinite version of
$$
\frac{(a_1+...+a_n)^2}{n}\le a_1^2+...+a_n^2.
$$
Namely, if $a_i\ge 0$ and  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i=A $ , whether there is inequlity like
$$
(\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i)^2  \le f(A) \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2  ~~~~~?
$$
But seemly, the Holder inequation implies the inequality like the above does not exist, so I ask here, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is not. To see this, simply note that there exists a sequence of sequences $a_{i,n}$ such that $\sum_{i} a_{i,n}=1$ for every $n$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i} a_{i,n}^2=0$.

Let $a_{i,n}=\frac{1}{n}$ for $i\leq n$ and $0$ else. Then, $\sum_{i} a_{i,n}=1$ by definition, but
$$
\sum_{i} a_{i,n}^2=\frac{1}{n}
$$
Thus, there is no general $\ell^2$-inequality of the form, you desire, even for series which are both $\ell^2$- and $\ell^1$-convergent.

Note, of course, that you would also get a counter example if $a_i$ is any sequence which is in $\ell^2$ but not in $\ell^1$. I just assumed it would be more interesting to see that it fails even if we condition on both sides of the inequality being finite.